# replace rows of n(n>=2) '*' symbols with n/2 '+' symbols

Tags: c

Only using getchar() and putchar(). For example having entered `"asf****f*d"` you get `"asf++f*d"`. The signal of the input's end is the symbol `'.'`. My best attempt is:

```
char c = 0, flag = 0; int k = 0;
while ((c = getchar()) !='.')
{
    if (c == '*') { k++; flag = 1; } else putchar(c);
    if (flag) 
    {
        if (c != '*')
        {
            flag = 0;
            if (k == 1) { putchar('*'); k = 0; continue; }
            for (int i = 0; i< k/2; i++)
                putchar('+');
            k = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This code does not work. I tried to swap those two if's:

```
 char c = 0, flag = 0; int k = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) !='.')
    {

        if (flag) 
        {
            if (c != '*')
            {
                flag = 0;
                if (k == 1) { putchar('*'); k = 0; continue; }
                for (int i = 0; i< k/2; i++)
                    putchar('+');
                k = 0;
            }
        }
        if (c == '*') { k++; flag = 1; } else putchar(c);
    }
```

but after doing that symbols after single '*' are not printed, that is inputting `"asf****f*d"` I get `"asf++f*"`

Comment: Can't understand what your problem is?

Comment: What does the posted code do? Does it work? Does it compile? Does it give the required output?

Comment: Have you traced your code, by hand?

Comment: "This code does not work" -- So what *does* it do? C'mon, be helpful if you want help. "My best attempt" -- I'll bet you can do better. Think a little deeper about the problem, rather than just doing a direct but naïve implementation of the literal problem description. Reworded, it says to replace each pair of '*' with a '+'.

Answer (score 1):

Your second attempt had the best chance of success, but the flow of control got messed up due to your use of `continue`. Many people find comfort in this statement, but in this case it is just a bad `goto`. Please use `else` to escape your nested `if`s; draw an [NSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nassi%E2%80%93Shneiderman_diagram) if you find this difficult. Currently, `continue` skips the `putchar(c)` in your second code sample, which explains the loss of the character following the single star.

There is another issue though; if the closing period is immediately preceded by a list of stars, then the replacement plusses will *not* be printed. This is caused by the fact that you save up all stars and print the replacing plusses all in one go. This 'buffering' demands a 'flush'. Though this is not difficult (print the pending plusses after the outer loop has finished), it does make your code messier. I strongly recommend to slightly change your algorithm. Instead of saving up stars, just print a single plus for every second star. This will make your code simpler and cleaner, and a 'flush' is no longer necessary.

I could of course give you a complete solution, but where's the fun in that?